# Remove all special characters and numbers and stop words

Tags: python

I have a list of issues like below and I would like to remove all special characters, numbers from this list of issues and i would like to do tokenization and stop words removal from this issues list:

```
    issue=[[hi iam !@going $%^ to uk&*(us \\r\\ntomorrow {morning} by 
            the_way two-three!~`` [problems]:are there;]
           [happy"journey" (and) \\r\\n\\rbring 576 chachos?>]]
```

I have tried below code but I am not getting desired output:

```
import re
ab=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', issue)
bc=re.split(r's, ab)
```

I would like to see output like below:

```
issue_output=[['hi','going','uk','us','tomorrow','morning',
                'way','two','three','problems' ]
              [ 'happy','journey','bring','chachos']]
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Because from what I see, your issue list is very badly formatted which would cause the substitution not work in the first place.

Comment: Please edit `issue` list.

Answer (score 3):

There are two glaring problems with the code that you have posted. First is that your input list `issue` is not formatted properly which makes it impossible to parse. Depending on the way you actually want it formatted, the answer to your question might change, but in general, this leads to the second problem, which is that you are trying to do `re.sub` on a list. You want to do the substitution on the list's elements. You can use list comprehension for that:

`issue_output = [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', item) for item in issue]`

Since there is no valid Python list provided in the question, I will assume the values in the list based on my best guess.

```
issue = [
          ['hi iam !@going $%^ to uk&*(us \\r\\ntomorrow {morning} by the_way two-three!~`` [problems]:are there;'], 
          ['happy"journey" (and) \\r\\n\\rbring 576 chachos?>']
      ]
```

In this case, when you have a list of lists of strings, you need to adjust the list comprehension for that.

```
cleaned_issue = [[re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', item) for item in inner_list] for inner_list in issue]
```

This returns a list of lists with strings inside:

```
[['hi iam going to uk us r ntomorrow morning by the way two three problems are there '], ['happy journey and r n rbring 576 chachos ']]
```

If you want to have the separate words in that list, simply `split()` them after substitution.

```
tokenized_issue = [[re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', item.split()) for item in inner_list][0] for inner_list in issue]
```

This gives the result of:

```
[['hi', 'iam', 'going', 'to', 'uk', 'us', 'r', 'ntomorrow', 'morning', 'by', 'the', 'way', 'two', 'three', 'problems', 'are', 'there'], ['happy', 'journey', 'and', 'r', 'n', 'rbring', '576', 'chachos']]
```

Comment: this i have tried but it seems bit difficult to do tokenization. if u hava a idea to do tokenization n stop word removal it would be a great thing

Comment: @PraveenKumar I will gladly try to help you with that but you should update your question with properly formatted input and output list before I do that. At the moment, it is impossible to teel what _exactly_ you want to do.

Comment: change the `''` to a `'-'` or whatever you want, and split on that after the sub has run

Comment: @AlexanderRossa Thanks for ur support. just now i have modified my question. still if u have any confusion please ask for clarification from my side. thanks

Comment: @PraveenKumar The edit that you have made did not address the actual problem with your question. The issue list that you provided is not a valid Python list and it does not contain any strings. The desired output list is also missing various strings from the input list for no apparent reason. That is what I meant by updating your question.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa why desired output has missing strings means it is not containing any stop words. but it's should not be a string list. it should be list of lists. i think with this input we can't do tokenization and stop words removing y bcoz toknization function will accept only string input to do tokenization and stopwords remove. but i need output as a list of lists.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Since you still have not provided correct input, I assumed the form of the input. Have a look at my updated answer for whether this answers your question.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa i'm trying to reach u through linkdin to explain my problem clearly. but i can't reach u. if possible try to reach u linkedin

Comment: @PraveenKumar Any clarification of your problem should be done here, on StackOverflow, where it can be of benefit to others looking for answers to their questions. If you want to discuss your problem further, that's what comments are for. With that said, rather than you trying to explain your problem once again, try to read what I wrote about it so far and update your question accordingly. Your input list is incorrectly formatted which is why you are not getting the output you desire.